# Finding/hiring help with server administration

Tags: php, server, hiring

I need to install the fileinfo extension for PHP on my server. My hosting service does not support help with this. I know I could learn it and do it myself, but since I am an independent contractor and I know that server administration is the weakest part of my abilities, a DIY approach is going to cost me a lot more time than I can afford.

What is the best way to go about hiring a trustworthy contractor to either install the fileinfo extension for me or to train me in how to do this. Thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at sites like Elance or Odesk for a highly recommended person in this area. I've had a lot of success with hiring people from Odesk as long as I only hire people with good ratings.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to like the StackExchange model, I'd check out [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/). You can post the job on there, and get a good idea of who the applicant is based on their reputation on Stack Overflow.

There is one caveat, though - posting jobs costs money. I believe Jeff does this mostly to keep out the noise (and possibly da funk), but it's something that you might want to take into consideration.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. Unfortunately that is way out of my price range. It's good to know about though.